# Input ints separated by whitespace and pass them to an int array

Tags: c, arrays, input

I'm trying to write a program in C where the user inputs a defined number of ints (in this case 5 ints) separated by whitespaces. Then, the input is stored in an int array so, lastly, it can be stored in a char array.

As an example of how the program is intended to work, when it asks for an input:

```
Input: 20 5 63 4 127
```

The output of the program should be:

```
Output: 20 5 63 4 127
```

This is what I've written so far, but I don't know how to get the input transformed into an int array. Note that I know the length of the input beforehand (in this case, as said above, 5 ints).

```
// Input: 20 5 63 4 127


// Ask for user input.

// Store the input in this int array.
int input_int_array[5];

unsigned char char_array[5];

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    char_array[i]=input_int_array[i];

    printf("%d ", char_array[i]);
}

// Should print: 20 5 63 4 127
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. I suggest you read a tutorial about input in C.

Comment: Why would an input of 5 produce an output of 50? Is that just a typo?

Comment: @TimRandall it was a typo, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably expected to use `scanf()` to read user input as integers into an array of `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int input_int_array[5];

    // Ask for user input.
    printf("input 5 numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        // Store the input into the array.
        if (scanf("%d", &input_int_array[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    // Output the contents of the array:
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", input_int_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```